# NDSolve for four differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

actually i want to get a nice graph from these 4 equation (see picture below) but I cant get it. This is my code

```
s = NDSolve[{c'[
 t] == (2*9.5*10^(-33))*(0.2*(a[t]*a[t]*a[t]*a[t]*b[t] - 
      2*a[t]*a[t]*b[t]*d[t]*d[t] + a[t]*a[t]*b[t] + 
      a[t]*a[t]*d[t]*c[t] + d[t]*c[t])) - a[t]*a[t]*d[t]*5.74,
d'[t] == (a[t]*
   a[t]*0.2*(9.5*10^(-33))*(a[t]*a[t] - 2*d[t]*d[t] + 1)) + 
 c[t] , a'[t] == 
a[t]*(1/(1 + a[t]*a[t]))*
  d[t]*0.2*(9.5*10^(-33))*(-2*a[t]*a[t]*a[t]*a[t] + 
    2*a[t]*a[t]*d[t]*d[t] - a[t]*a[t] + 1) + 2*a[t]*b[t], 
b'[t] == (1/2*a[t]*a[t]*a[t]*a[t]) - (1/(2*1.414*a[t]*a[t]*a[t]) - 
   5.74*(9.5*10^(-33)) (a[t]*a[t] + 2*d[t]*d[t] + 1) - 
   2*b[t]*b[t]), c[0] == 0.25, d[0] == -12, a[0] == 1, 
b[0] == 0}, {d, c, a, b}, {t, 0, 120}]
```

then i want to create a graph

```
Plot[Evaluate[d[t] /. s], {t, 0, 120}]
```

why i can't get this graph. What is wrong with my code? Please help me. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: `NDSolve` fails at about `t == 1.4`, where `a` and `b` begin growing faster than exponentially.  To see what is happening in detail, drop the terms with very small coefficients.  Then, `a` and `b` decouple from `c` and `d`, and you can apply `NDSolve` to `a` and `b` only: `{Derivative[1][a][t] == 2 a[t] b[t], Derivative[1][b][t] == -(250/(707 a[t]^3)) + a[t]^4/2 + 2 b[t]^2, 
 a[0] == 1, b[0] == 0}`  The computations fails in the same way, probably because this runaway behavior is inherent in the equations.  I suggest you check their validity.

Comment: why in the world are you doing `a[t]*a[t]*a[t]*a[t]` instead of `a[t]^4` ? And you really should define parameters and use them instead of using literal numbers in the expressions. If you make it more readable it will be easier to see mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewrite the whole system in *Mathematica*, so, I don't know what you were missing.

The results are promising but are not the exact replica. Which maybe because of the missing initial condition on `b[t]`.

```
xi = Exp[-d[t]^2/(a[t]^2 + 1)]/(a[t]^2 + 1)^(5/2); N1 = Sqrt[Pi]*A^2*a[t]; W0 = 0.2; A = 1;

eq1 = v'[t] == (2*xi)*(W0*(a[t]^4*b[t] - 2*a[t]^2*b[t]*d[t]^2 + a[t]^2*b[t] + 
        a[t]^2*d[t]*v[t] + d[t]*v[t]) - a[t]^2*d[t]*V0);

eq2 = d'[t] == a[t]^2*W0*xi*(a[t]^2 - 2*d[t]^2 + 1) + v[t];

eq3 = a'[t] == a[t]*(1/(1 + a[t]^2))*d[t]*W0*xi*(-2*a[t]^4 + 2*a[t]^2*d[t]^2 - a[t]^2 + 1) 
        + 2*a[t]*b[t];

eq4 = b'[t] == (1/(2*a[t]^4)) - N1/(2*Sqrt[2*Pi]*a[t]^3) - V0*xi (a[t]^2 + 2*d[t]^2 + 1) 
       - 2*b[t]^2;

s = ParametricNDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, v[0] == 0.25, d[0] == -12, a[0] == 1,
                       b[0] == 0.0}, {v, d, a, b}, {t, 0, 120}, {V0}];

V0vals = {{V0 -> 5.74}, {V0 -> 5.89}, {V0 -> 6.11}}

Plot[Evaluate[d[V0][t] /. s /. V0vals], {t, 0, 120}, PlotRange -> All, 
                PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], Green, Directive[Blue, Dashed]}]
```

[image]

Comment: i want to ask another questions 1., after we get the value of d[t], a[t], b[t], v[t] from code above, then now, how i can get d''[t] from the solution that solved by code above? 2. then how to integrate that value; integrate( -d''[t] d d)?